# Pop up com jquery antes de fechar o navegador

Tags: jquery, html, css

Galera gostaria de fazer um pop up que apareça antes que a pessoa feche a aba do navegador igual a do shoptime:
http://www.shoptime.com.br/

Não tenho muito conhecimento em Javascript, muito menos em jquery. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Seja mais especifico, eu tenho adblock e não vi nenhum pop up

Comment: O único pop up que apareceu aqui foi o de carregamento da página, sendo assim você poderia usar o método `$(document).ready()` ou método `$(window).load()`. Se for outro pop-up especifique melhor como acha-lo por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [**fancybox**](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox), veja abaixo:

```
$(function() {

    var content = '<div id="conteudo" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">Sua propaganda aqui!</div>';
    $.fancybox.open([{
                   type: 'inline',
                   autoScale: true,
                   minHeight: 30,
                   content: content,
                   closeBtn:true
                  }], { padding: 0 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue fazer esse efeito com um plugin chamado [OuiBounce](http://carlsednaoui.github.io/ouibounce/).

---

Depois de instalar o plugin e chamá-lo na página, crie uma div oculta com um id para ela, por exemplo:

```
<div id="ouibounce-modal">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-title">
      <h3>Modal de Exemplo</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Exemplo</p>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <p>Fechar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

E chame um javascript para atribuir o evento do OuiBounce para essa div

```
var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal'), {
        aggressive: true,
        timer: 0,
        callback: function() {
           _ouibounce.disable();
        }
      });

  $('body').on('click', function() {
    $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
  });
# Essa função vai fechar o modal quando eu clicar fora dele #

  $('#ouibounce-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function() {
    $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
  });
# Essa função vai fechar o modal quando eu clicar no botão 'Fechar' #

  $('#ouibounce-modal .modal').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
# Essa função vai impedir o modal de ser fechado se eu clicar dentro dele #
```